# How to dynamically change value of count bubble in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Perhaps I'm missing the obvious, but I'm searching for an option to change the value of a count bubble in js code. I've seen many solutions in building up the html of the Unsorted List in JavaScript, but that is not what I'm looking for.

In the html I have (simplified)

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mainPageSelection"   data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#1"><img src="ca.png"  class="ui-li-icon">Browse Catalog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2"><img src="se.png"  class="ui-li-icon">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3"><img src="sh.png"  class="ui-li-icon" >Shopping Cart<span class="ui-li-count" id="test"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the value of the count bubble of the ListView entry "Shopping Cart". 
I know that if I place a number just between the opening and closing tags of span, I see the count bubble number.

What I'm looking for is a way to dynamically add the number here. If I use for example

```
$(#"test").attr("value", 42)
```

it doesn't work. I can see in the Element Inspector on Safari that value="80" is added within the opening tag of span but I want to add a value between the opening and closing tag of span so that it shows on the bubble...
Any help or ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Text elements like `span` doesn't have value, so attribute `value` has no special meaning. You should set a text of the span with `text` or `html` methods:

```
$("#test").text(42);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nsczgo96/

Comment: Indeed, I missed the obvious. Thanks.